# How to add Layer to UIButton subclass in Protocol oriented way in swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uibutton, protocols

I want to learn programming in protocol oriented manner. And I want that `StartButton` and `StopButton` subclasses both just conform to `Roundable` protocol, so that they'll have a rounded layer inside of them.

Right now my StartButton subclass looks like this:

```
  var backgroundLayer: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()


  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    backgroundLayer.fillColor = Colors.Background.button.cgColor
    backgroundLayer.rasterizationScale = 2.0 * UIScreen.main.scale
    backgroundLayer.shouldRasterize = true
    layer.addSublayer(backgroundLayer)
  }

  override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    backgroundLayer.path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: self.bounds).cgPath
  }
```

Whats the best way to do that with a protocols approach?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to use a protocol to share code, then the shared code needs to go into a protocol extension.

Your protocol will also need to include the `layer` and `backgroundLayer` properties so they can be accessible in the protocol extension.

Comment: do you have an example of this. How can a backgroundLayer be added at initialization of a button?

Comment: Actually, it makes more sense to create a UIButton subclass where you implement the shape stuff, and then have `StartButton` and `StopButton` inherit from that. Protocols are for describing behavior visible to other objects, but having a round shape is more of an internal implementation detail. So this isn't a good case to practice using protocols.

Comment: ok, thanks for this. I'll try protocols in some other more appropriate cases.